# ¿De qué manera se determinan los Usuarios huérfanos en una BD de Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

**Buenos días,**

Estoy haciendo un script que me genera los usuarios huérfanos en SQL Server (concepto muy conocido en SQL). Pero no encuentro un equivalente en Oracle (Tal vez no se dé). Sólo ví una consulta que decía sobre `sinónimos huérfanos`, no sé si es lo mismo. Además no sé si se puede dar un caso donde un esquema pueda estar sin un Usuario asociado como sucedería en SQL (usuarios sin un login asociado). Solo pude encontrar otra consulta sobre `Objetos Inválidos` pero este hace mención a objetos que no están dentro de un esquema por lo que entiendo.

En definitiva quisera descartar en mi informe que "No existe el concepto de Usuarios Huérfanos en Oracle".

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hablas de usuarios huérfanos en SQL Server, parece que te refieres a lo que se describe en este documentación: [Solucionar problemas de usuarios huérfanos (SQL Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server), donde en parte explica:

> Los usuarios huérfanos en SQL Server se producen cuando un usuario de base de datos se basa en un inicio de sesión en la base de datos `maestra` , pero ese inicio de sesión ya no existe en `master`. Esto puede suceder cuando se elimina el inicio de sesión o cuando la base de datos se mueve a otro servidor donde el inicio de sesión no existe. En este tema se describe cómo buscar usuarios huérfanos para reasignarles inicios de sesión.

O sea que, en SQL Server, existe una distinción entre el usuario de base de datos y el inicio de sesión. Y el usuario puede quedar huérfano si su inicio de sesión correspondiente ya no existe.

En Oracle no existe este distinción. El usuario de base de datos es lo único que se necesita para poder establecer una conexión y acceder a sus datos. No existe un concepto separado de inicio de sesión como lo hay en SQL Server. De modo que en Oracle, no tienes que preocuparte de que un usuario pueda quedar huérfano.

---

Notas adicionales:

> ví una consulta que decía sobre *sinónimos huérfanos*, no sé si es lo mismo

No es lo mismo. En Oracle puedes crear un sinónimo, o sea darle otro nombre, a cualquier tipo de objeto. Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes una tabla `X`. Puedes crear un sinónimo `Z` que apunte a esta tabla, de modo que si haces `select * from Z`, en realidad equivale a consultar la tabla `X`. Pero si borras la tabla `X`, entonces el sinónimo `Z` queda huérfano.

> Además no sé si se puede dar un caso donde un esquema pueda estar sin un Usuario asociado como sucedería en SQL (usuarios sin un login asociado)

Cuidado, que aquí estás mezclando 3 conceptos diferentes. En SQL Server, el usuario, el esquema y el login son 3 cosas distintas. En cierta forma, se puede decir que en Oracle los 3 conceptos vienen siendo lo mismo: el usuario. En Oracle, el usuario tiene un esquema asociado. El esquema no puede existir sin su usuario asociado, son básicamente la misma cosa. Y no existe un concepto separado de login o inicio de sesión.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración sstan's, solo una última consulta, ¿Un usuario puede tener varios esquemas? O es necesario tener un usuario para cada esquema creado...

Comment: Depende de lo que entiendas por *tener* un esquema. Si es en el sentido de que le *pertenezcan* varios esquemas, entonces la respuesta es no.  El usuario y el esquema son la misma cosa. Cuando creas un usuario, automaticamente llega a existir un esquema con el mismo nombre que el usuario, y ese es el único que le pertenece. Sin embargo, un usuario puede *acceder* a los objetos de otros esquemas/usuarios si estos le dan permiso para hacerlo.